# Cursor seems to return an empty set?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, cursors

When executing the following Postgres script in pgAdmin I see an empty result set.

```sql
create OR replace function xtest(inout rc refcursor) 
language plpgsql 
as $$
begin 
   open rc for select unnest('{1,2,3}'::int2[]) id;
end;
$$;

begin;
select * from xtest('a');
fetch all from a;
close a;
commit;
```

Shouldn't this return rows "1,2,3"?
What sort of adjustments does it need?

Comment: Works for me: https://dbfiddle.uk/_dkZGut1

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter you mean the script works on your machine ?

Comment: Yes. As well as in the given fiddle.

Comment: in #pgadmin an empty result set is returned

Comment: I tested with pgAdmin and it works as expected. You need to stay within the same transaction, and after `FETCH ALL`, the next `FETCH` is empty, of course. I rarely use explicit cursors. Cases where those are the best solution are far and few between.

Comment: What you have discovered is you should use a client other the pgAdmin4. It has too many quirks.  In this case only displaying the output of the last command which is `commit;` and eating the output of `fetch all from a;`.  My choice is [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html). There is a learning curve but in the end you will be more productive, if for no other reason then you will spend less time here asking why your client is failing you.

Comment: I want to replace long functions that returns a query with this
Imagine like > 20 cols

Answer (score 1):

Works for me. Locally as well as in this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_dkZGut1).
Works using pgAdmin, too, of course.

I am pretty sure the confusion arises from the fact that pgAdmin only displays the result of the last executed command. So if you execute the whole block, you get an empty result from the last command, which is `commit` in your example.
pgAdmin suffers from a **minor bug** in this regard: since `COMMIT` does not return data, the most recently used column name(s) ("id" in the example) is displayed with empty result.

**Solution:**

Execute one command at a time. The explicit `BEGIN` starts a transaction, which persists until closed.

Comment: finally it worked 
i wonder when running some actual query using node-pg 
`pool.query(...)`  do I need begin end or should I go with DO or what ?

Comment: First question: is a cursor actually the best tool for this? If so, and you cannot stay within the same transaction, consider an [SQL cursor `WITH HOLD`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-declare.html) - different from PL/pgSQL cursor.